# Detect termination of Application, Android

Tags: android, session-variables, android-lifecycle

I need a method to detect when my application is closing, so that I can tell a web-server to clear my session variable that it's storing. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your application extends Activity.

You could use the `onDestroy()` method:

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) :

> *onDestroy() is* The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

Your code would look like this:

```
public class YourAppActivity extends Activity {
     ...
     ...

     @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();
         //clear your session variable. 
         //you may want to do this quick, and on another thread 
         //to prevent android from killing your app
     }
 }
```

Comment: Also from the Docs: "There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away." So there is no guarantee that `onDestroy()` will be called when the application terminates.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `onDestroy()` which is run when the app is being destroyed by the system or `onStop()` when the app loses visibility (often prior to destroying).  You code would then look something like this:

`public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
//Enter your code here to do stuff
}`

However, on destroying your app the variables used by it will be destroyed along with it.

See: [How to release or clear the value of variable or object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716130/how-to-release-or-clear-the-value-of-variable-or-object)

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create static variable for counter of integer type. On OnCreate method Increment variable by 1  and on OnDestroy() Method decrement the variable value. and on OnDestroy() Method check the static variable value is 0 or not if it is 0 then call the webservice to clear the session

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Activity's **onDestroy()** method checking whether the user is terminating the app or the OS is killing the process' activities because of low memory with the **isFinishing()** method. To deploy the "Destroy web session" logic, you could start an IntentService to start this action.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

check 
[Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and 
i think you can do it on `onDestroy()`